# How to parallelize a nested loop by OpenMP?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

This code fragment solves a system of linear equations using the simple iteration method:

```cpp
    int n_iter;
    double error = eps + 1;
    double *x_new = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    double *Ax = (double *)malloc(N * sizeof(double));
    for (n_iter = 0; error >= eps; n_iter++) {
        error = 0;
        init_vector(Ax, N, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // find the Ax vector
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                Ax[i] += A[i * N + j] * x[j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {  // find the new x and calculate the error
            x_new[i] = x[i] - tau * (Ax[i] - b[i]);
            error += pow(x_new[i] - x[i], 2);
        }
        error = sqrt(error);
        
        // Update the x vector
        double *t = x;
        x = x_new;
        x_new = t;
    }
```

I need to parallelize it by creating a single parallel section `#pragma omp parallel` that encompasses the entire iterative algorithm.
The reason for not simply parallelizing the two nested loops is that dividing the program into threads on each iteration of the outer loop will add overhead.
I don't understand how to do it. It needs to preserve the order of execution for the outer loop and parallelize the nested loops, with a single `#pragma omp parallel` before the outer loop.
I don't like the idea of manually dividing iterations among processes because it would be difficult to achieve dynamic load balancing.
The whole code: https://pastebin.com/zUeAeLU9

I assumed that something like this would work:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    for (n_iter = 0; error >= eps; n_iter++) {
        #pragma omp single 
        {
            error = 0;
            init_vector(Ax, N, 0);
        }
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                Ax[i] += A[i * N + j] * x[j];
            }
            
            x_new[i] = x[i] - tau * (Ax[i] - b[i]);
            error += pow(x_new[i] - x[i], 2);
        }
        #pragma omp barrier
        
        #pragma omp single
        {
            error = sqrt(error);
            
            // Update the x vector
            double *t = x;
            x = x_new;
            x_new = t;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the executable file is launched, but nothing happens. Even the test printf statements left in the code are not working.
The whole code v2: https://pastebin.com/yfbTfR56

Comment: I'm not completly sure this approach can work, but at the very least you have race conditions on `n_iter` and `error`. `n_iter` should be `private` (or better, declared in the loop header), and you should have a reduction on `error`: `#pragma omp for reduction(+:error)`. The barrier is probably not needed, as there is an implicit barrier at the end of parallel for loops.

Comment: @PierU ur right, these were mistakes, but after correcting, it still isn't working

Comment: What does mean "isn't working", precisely? Runtime error? Infinite loop? other? Did you try debugging, either with a debugger or some prints? To really help, we would need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: About your initial concern, that is *" The reason for not simply parallelizing the two nested loops is that dividing the program into threads on each iteration of the outer loop will add overhead"*, you should not worry too much about that: OpenMP does not destroy the threads right at the end of a parallel region, but rather reuse existing threads, so it does not have to recreate them.